# JavaScript client checks if URL is an image

Tags: javascript, jquery

The browser gets a list of external URLs, and I want to filter the ones that are images.

The URLs are on other domains, so I think I can only do this using a [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) dataType.

```
function checkImageURL(url){
    var isImage = false;
    $.ajax({
      type : "GET",
      dataType : "jsonp",
      url : url,
      success: function(data){
        console.log("Success was returned => a JSON file was returned");
        return false;
      },
      error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
          console.log(url);
          console.log(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
          if(jqXHR.status === 404){
              console.log('Is image');
              return true;
          }
          else if(jqXHR.status === 200){
              console.log('Not image');
              return false;
          }
          else{
              console.log("new status!",jqXHR.status);
              return false;
          }
      }
    });
}

checkImageURL("https://en.wikipedia.org/404");//404 page
checkImageURL("http://www.sheldonbrown.com/web_sample1.html");//HTML page
checkImageURL("http://sites.duke.edu/jc319/files/2014/03/yellow-disney-pixar-cars-33967438-3507-2481.jpg");//Real image
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vubxzmbh/7/)

Results:

```
GET https://en.wikipedia.org/404?callback=jQuery21307281952630728483_1435482371527&_=1435482371528 404 (Not Found)
https://en.wikipedia.org/404
Object {readyState: 4, status: 404, statusText: "error"} "error" "error"
Is image

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
http://www.sheldonbrown.com/web_sample1.html
Object {readyState: 4, status: 200, statusText: "load"} ........
Not image

Refused to execute script from 'http://sites.duke.edu/jc319/files/2014/03/yellow-disney-pixar-cars-33967438…2481.jpg?callback=jQuery21307281952630728483_1435482371531&_=1435482371532' because its MIME type ('image/jpeg') is not executable.
http://sites.duke.edu/jc319/files/2014/03/yellow-disney-pixar-cars-33967438-3507-2481.jpg
Object {readyState: 4, status: 404, statusText: "error"} "error" "error"
Is image
```

My issue now is that a 404 page and a real image both return the same error (a 404). The browser itself throws a different error for each, but apparently I can't catch those ones.

I am kind of stuck right now, so either it's not possible to do, either there is a completely different solution?

Answer (score 2):

Leave the `dataType` empty since you don't know what the response content is. Instead set `crossDomain` to true in your ajax request.

If you get a success response that still doesn't mean the response is an image so check for the content type:

```
success: function(response, status, xhr){ 
    var ct = xhr.getResponseHeader("content-type") || "";
    console.log((ct.indexOf('image') > -1) ? "is image" : "not image");
}
```

Comment: Actually I think if I get a success it means I got a json file (since I am using a jsonp dataType) so I should just return false.

Comment: I am not sure if we are using the same browsers but on chrome I am still getting a """No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://fiddle.jshell.net' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404""" if I don't put jsonp in the dataType: http://jsfiddle.net/h73chr5w/.

Comment: From what I found, crossDomain:true is almost never needed, the only case where it is is if you want to do a same-origin request while treating it like a cross-origin request. Since we're making a cross-origin request, it's already going to be true by default.